# How to compute an agregate from a specific set of keys for each record in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
id  pid     tran1 tran2
1   1,2,3,4 5     3
2   2,4     10    6
3   3       15    9
4   4       20    12
```

I have the above data set.

I need to perform an aggregation on tran1 and tran2 columns for all the elements in pid column for a given id. For example, for id=1: I will be aggregating (summing) data from records with id equals 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.

The desired output is:

```
id pid      tran1   tran2
1  1,2,3,4  50      30
2  2,4      30      18
3  3        15      9
4  4        20      12
```

Comment: Are you new to Spark? Can you please rewrite/fix your question? It's hard to understand it. Maybe add the desired output for a given input

Comment: @anurag_udasi please mark my answer as final answer if it solve your issue.

Comment: @Nikk - this is adding all the values for fist key only so lets say if 1 has tran_1 value = 10 and if it has child has other value its adding 10 equal to number of child so its actully not taking its child tran_1 values for computation

Comment: can you provide exact data with details example like how you want

Comment: @Nikk - Thanks for response. I have updated my question. You can reffer new values.

Comment: @anurag_udasi I have updated my answer on the basis of you requirements. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> df.show
+---+-------+-----+-----+
| id|    pid|tran1|tran2|
+---+-------+-----+-----+
|  1|1,2,3,4|    5|    3|
|  2|    2,4|   10|    6|
|  3|      3|   15|    9|
|  4|      4|   20|   12|
+---+-------+-----+-----+

scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("pid", explode(split(col("pid"), ",")))

scala> val df2 = df1.alias("df1").join(df.alias("df"), col("df1.pid") === col("df.id"),"left").select(col("df1.id"),col("df1.pid"),col("df.tran1"),col("df.tran2"))

scala> df2.show
+---+---+-----+-----+
| id|pid|tran1|tran2|
+---+---+-----+-----+
|  1|  1|    5|    3|
|  1|  2|   10|    6|
|  1|  3|   15|    9|
|  1|  4|   20|   12|
|  2|  2|   10|    6|
|  2|  4|   20|   12|
|  3|  3|   15|    9|
|  4|  4|   20|   12|
+---+---+-----+-----+

scala> df2.groupBy(col("id")).agg(concat_ws(",",collect_list(col("pid"))).alias("pid"), sum(col("tran1")).alias("tran1"), sum(col("tran2")).alias("tran2")).orderBy(col("id")).show(false)
+---+-------+-----+-----+
|id |pid    |tran1|tran2|
+---+-------+-----+-----+
|1  |1,2,3,4|50.0 |30.0 |
|2  |2,4    |30.0 |18.0 |
|3  |3      |15.0 |9.0  |
|4  |4      |20.0 |12.0 |
+---+-------+-----+-----+
```